# What do "watched tags" and "ignored tags" do?

Tags: support, tags, faq-proposed, tag-watching

- What are **watched tags** and **ignored tags**? How do they work?
- What are **tag subscriptions**?
- What are **interesting tags**?
- On Stack Overflow, the content of the main page question list appears to be influenced by watched and ignored tags. How does that work?

> For more information, see "[How do I find topics I'm interested in?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics)" in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help).

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: Any specific reason for copying it here on MSO from [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do)?

Comment: @AzizShaikh http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow#comment5724_251225

Answer (score 23):

**Watched Tags**: Questions with these tags become highlighted, formerly known as "interesting tags" and "favorite tags".

**Ignored Tags**: Questions with these tags are shown faded; they are still visible but less prominent. Checking the "Hide Ignored Tags" box causes them to be hidden completely. (This is done by a client-side script however, so you may notice odd "gaps.")

The ignored tags list takes precedence over the watched tags list. This means that if a question has a tag that is in your ignored tags list it will be treated as ignored, regardless of whether or not it also contains a tag that is in your watched tags list.

On Stack Overflow, these preferences affect how questions are displayed on the home ("Recent questions") page and the various questions pages.

These options appear in the sidebar of the main page and under the user preference page (note that [you can use wildcards](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/) to highlight or exclude multiple related tags):

[image: user-editable lists of tags]

#### See also: [Expressing Your Tag Preferences](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/10/21/expressing-your-tag-preferences).

You can also see questions with the tags from your watch list:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tab=Unanswered&tagMode=Watched

[image]