# Is it possible to ignore tags that are related to each other?

Tags: discussion, tags, ignored-tags

For example `angularjs` and these.

- angularjs-directive
- angularjs-scope
- angularjs-ng-repeat
- angularjs-service
- angularjs-routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [proposed FAQ about ignored tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251970/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do), you can [use wildcards in your ignored tags list](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/), on [your preferences page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/2311366).