# Language Forums

Tags: feature-request

I would really like it if there were pages for each programming language, I'm new to the whole concept of programming and I tend to gravitate towards the obscure. Batch and C#.

The problem I'm having is I don't understand what anyone is taking about and I am finding it hard to differentiate between languages and participate in the forums.

Eventually I would like to learn more about HTML and PHP but trying to pick out the related posts is kind of hard for a newbie like myself.

Comment: [tag:batch-file], [tag:c++]? Both have tag wikis full of information.

Comment: We tried that, the [documentation project unfortunately failed](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation).

Comment: Batch and C# are hardly obscure. C# is one of the most popular languages on the planet.

Comment: Supplementing the comments and answer already given: the Stack Overflow concept is *not* that of a "forum". It's not meant to be a discussion site. Stack Overflow is designed as a Q&A (question and answer) database. A place where *programmers* who have a specific problem with code they're writing go to find answers for that *specific*, narrowly targeted problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some tips:

- Do learn what [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) are
- Read their wiki's, for example [C# tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info)
- Learn how to use [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), specially its operators [`[c#] closed:no is:q score:10`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+closed%3Ano+is%3Aq+score%3A10)
- Setup your [watched and ignored tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251970/what-do-watched-tags-and-ignored-tags-do)
- Read the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help), the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) posts and if you're into asking questions, [the question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
- And if you're new: [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Also be careful about with what mindset you come to Stack Overflow. We are a Question and Answer site. That is [different from a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums). We are here to create content for future visitors. That might conflict with personal and/or short term needs.

Comment: This is the answer to my could have been reworded question. I will check it all out thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Stack Overflow is not in-scope to be an introduction to programming.  This site and its participants are more aligned with the notion of answering questions to programming problems.

As "where do I start learning a language" isn't *really* a programming problem, you'll find little room to discuss the growing pains of being a programmer here.

There are better resources elsewhere on the Internet to do this - as mentioned before by rene, the tag wikis on certain tags will point you to tutorials or guides which will get you started.

Once you have a concrete problem with an application or piece of code you're writing, we'll welcome you here with open arms.